# Magento export out of memory even via SSH

Tags: php, magento, ssh, export

I have a relatively small store, about 20k skus all simple products. I'm using magento 1.7.2 but had the same problem with all the older versions. I simply cannot export my products to a CSV. Out of memory when running directly from the dataflow profiles in the magento backend and same error when running it from shell.

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 71 bytes) in /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Source/Table.php on line 62
```

I've increased the memory limits and execution times in magentos htaccess to 512m, magentos php.ini to 512m and my VPS php configuration ini to 512mb. it still burns through it in about 4 minutes and runs out of memory.

I'm so confused, my entire database (zipped) is only 28mb! what am I missing to make the magento export all products function work?

Comment: Did you try with `output_buffering` ?

Answer (score 3):

Magento dataflow does have a tendency to use massive amounts of memory making exports on large stores difficult. For stores with large product catalogues it is often a lot quicker and easier to write a script to export directly from the database rather than through dataflow.

Comment: Yes, I think you have quite correct data if you use product_flat setting and export the catalog_product_flat_x table (as a tip)?

Answer (score 0):

This might be problem with your `.htaccess` file(s) aren’t overriding your `memory_limit` settings globally set in `php.ini`.

Other option is set `memory_limit` to unlimited in you `index.php` for testing. Then you will come to know whether changes in .htaccess is not getting effected or not.

Comment: have you given memory_limit to `-1` ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by exporting 500, 1000 or as many as I wanted at a time (with a custom export script).

I made a file that received as parameters $start and $productsToExport. The file took the collection of products, and then used

```
LIMIT ($start-1)*$productsToExport, $productsToExport
```

This script only returned the number of products exported.

I made a second, master script that did a recursive AJAX to the first file, with the parameters $start = 0, $productsToExport = 500. When the AJAX was finished, it did the same with $start = 1, and so on, until no products are left.

The advantage of this is that it doesn't overload the server (one ajax is run only after the previous is finished) - and if an error occurs, the script continues. Also thememory_limit and max_execution_time are sa

Answer (score 0):

If by 20k skus you mean 20.000 then this is totally possible. The export is very hungry for memory, unfortunately. I always increase the memory_limit to 2000M in this case and then it takes a while to create the file, but succeeds in the end.